# Regex - return highest number

Tags: regex

Is it possible to write a regular expression that will return the HIGHEST numeric value that contains a decimal? If you look at the example below, the desired value to be returned is in bold.

> 5909 Illinois Road - TOTAL SALE 5543762952 COFLLE FILIERS W143000806
>   SALAD KIT 4 02/ 4.00 was 11.96 now *7143001073 PREMIUM KIT 2 02/ 5.00
>   was 7.98 now 6.94 G . 9^ 1.99 1 8.00 F 5.00 F TOTAL- IN n Sales Tax
>   TOTAL XKHHXXXXXHXK9367 (C) AID A0000001523ai0 TC 0710B0F2DB664SD0 NO
>   CVM REQUIRED .14 .14 **15.13** 15 13 NUMBER OF HEMS 7 Tx;39 Op:2164709
>   Tiii:143 St: 125 10:29:52

Comment: With regex, you can get a list of all the decimal numbers in the string. Then you can use a programming language to find the highest number among them. Once you try something and if it didn't work, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51690220/edit) your question, include a tag to the programming language you're using, and show us what you have tried so we can help you with it.

Comment: I find it cool that I found your question searching (bing.com) for the UPC 5543762952. Safeway in Fraser, Colorado marks the regular retail price $3.95 up to $4.29 (8.6% markup). Such is the cost of stocking stores in mountain communities. tbcj0305a

Answer (score 1):

No. Regular expressions have no innate way to evaluate value, so attempting to craft a regex to do that is a fool's errand.

Since you want to parse the data, write a parser instead and you'll be able to extract all of the floating point values instead.

Comment: You could do it in Perl using the (?{ ... }) extended pattern

Comment: Ok thanks. Unfortunately, the program that I'm using only allows for RegEx. What about returning the first numeric value (with decimal) following a specific word? For example, the word "REQUIRED" in the original content, would then return the value .14.

Comment: @JadonR looks like you are willing to use an inappropiate tool for certain problem. As Ahmed Abdelhameed states, you may use REGEX to parse and get the numbers array, but then you would require the help of another tool to programmatically calculate the MAX of them.